# qml item "menu" didn't stops process after choose "menuitem"

Tags: qt, qml

So my problem is:

`Menu` item's method `popup()` was connected to right mouse button click. When I click button all is working correct, but at the "click moment" new memory is allocating and the new process is creating. After selecting any of `MenuItem` the memory isn't freed and process will be still running.
So if you call `popup()` again it will allocate new memory and create new process again. And same will be every time

code sample:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4 as C4
C4.Menu {
    id: contextMenuFree
    C4.MenuItem {
        text: "Add Node"
        onTriggered: {
            //...
        }

    }
    C4.MenuSeparator { }
    C4.MenuItem {
        text: "test item"
    }
}

MouseArea {
  onPressed: {
    if (mouse.button === Qt.RightButton) {
       contextMenuFree.popup()
    }
  }
}
```

[image: process]
Qt 5.5, debian

Comment: What is `C4`? What do you mean with *new process is creating*?

Comment: @derM edited. Process - is a process) Maybe It was forked from main process or something else. I dont know how it was realized in Qt libs.